# How can I ensure that global variables are initialized in the correct order?

Tags: c++, c++14

I have global variables whose constructors rely on other global variables in different translation units. My understanding is that the order of initialization of global variables is unspecified, so this isn't safe.

How can I ensure that the globals I need will be initialized at the latest when they are first accessed? For instance, if I create a static variable in a function and call that function to get a reference, will it always be initialized the first time the function is executed?

Comment: Yes, that ought to work. For example, see the "Exception" section of [this](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Ri-singleton) guideline.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables

Comment: You're describing the [Construct On First Use Idiom](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order-on-first-use), and yes, that's a valid way to solve this problem.

Comment: _"I have global variables whose constructors rely on other global variables in different translation units."_ Eh, why? :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I have classes that model data types for reflection-like purposes and a set of common type-objects that I don't want copied in every translation unit if I can avoid it.

Comment: @zneak: I'm sure there are better ways to accomplish that than global variables and their unspecified initialisation order.

Comment: That's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the same method as that used for standard streams `std::cout` and its friends. It is called [Schwarz Counter or Nifty Counter](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter).

If you look into `ios_base.h` header of GNU `libstdc++`:

```
// 27.4.2.1.6  Class ios_base::Init
// Used to initialize standard streams. In theory, g++ could use
// -finit-priority to order this stuff correctly without going
// through these machinations.
class Init
{
  friend class ios_base;
public:
  Init();
  ~Init();

private:
  static _Atomic_word   _S_refcount;
  static bool       _S_synced_with_stdio;
};
```

And into `iostream` header:

```
namespace std _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)
{
_GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION

  extern istream cin;       /// Linked to standard input
  extern ostream cout;      /// Linked to standard output
  extern ostream cerr;      /// Linked to standard error (unbuffered)
  extern ostream clog;      /// Linked to standard error (buffered)

  // For construction of filebuffers for cout, cin, cerr, clog et. al.
  static ios_base::Init __ioinit;

_GLIBCXX_END_NAMESPACE_VERSION
} // namespace
```

And into `ios_init.cc`:

```
  ios_base::Init::Init()
  {
    if (__gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add_dispatch(&_S_refcount, 1) == 0)
      {
    // Standard streams default to synced with "C" operations.
    _S_synced_with_stdio = true;

    new (&buf_cout_sync) stdio_sync_filebuf<char>(stdout);
    new (&buf_cin_sync) stdio_sync_filebuf<char>(stdin);
    new (&buf_cerr_sync) stdio_sync_filebuf<char>(stderr);

    // The standard streams are constructed once only and never
    // destroyed.
    new (&cout) ostream(&buf_cout_sync);
    new (&cin) istream(&buf_cin_sync);
    new (&cerr) ostream(&buf_cerr_sync);
    new (&clog) ostream(&buf_cerr_sync);
    cin.tie(&cout);
    cerr.setf(ios_base::unitbuf);
    // _GLIBCXX_RESOLVE_LIB_DEFECTS
    // 455. cerr::tie() and wcerr::tie() are overspecified.
    cerr.tie(&cout);

    // NB: Have to set refcount above one, so that standard
    // streams are not re-initialized with uses of ios_base::Init
    // besides <iostream> static object, ie just using <ios> with
    // ios_base::Init objects.
    __gnu_cxx::__atomic_add_dispatch(&_S_refcount, 1);
      }
  }

  ios_base::Init::~Init()
  {
    // Be race-detector-friendly.  For more info see bits/c++config.
    _GLIBCXX_SYNCHRONIZATION_HAPPENS_BEFORE(&_S_refcount);
    if (__gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add_dispatch(&_S_refcount, -1) == 2)
      {
        _GLIBCXX_SYNCHRONIZATION_HAPPENS_AFTER(&_S_refcount);
    // Catch any exceptions thrown by basic_ostream::flush()
    __try
      { 
        // Flush standard output streams as required by 27.4.2.1.6
        cout.flush();
        cerr.flush();
        clog.flush();
      }
    __catch(...)
      { }
      }
  }
```

The above embeds a global object `__ioinit` with static storage duration into each translation unit (.o) that includes `iostream` header file. I.e. each `.o` gets its own copy of `__ioinit`.

All objects of fundamental types with static storage duration are zero-initialized on start-up during static initialization phase (on Linux this is `.bss` section of an elf object), hence `_S_refcount` is assigned 0 prior to dynamic initialization phase.

Next, during dynamic initialization phase constructors of these `__ioinit` objects are called. Each constructor increments `_S_refcount` and the `__ioinit` object that observes 0 value of `_S_refcount` resides in the translation unit that is being initialized first. This object's constructor initializes the standard streams.

There is more information in C++ Standard Library Defect Report List [Issue 369: io stream objects and static ctors](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#369).

---

You can use the same method to initialize your own global objects. E.g.:

```
// DynamicInitializer.h
template<class T>
struct DynamicInitializer
{
    // These members have to be POD types to be zero-initialized at static initialization phase
    // prior to the dynamic initialization phase which invokes constructors of global objects.
    static T* instance_;
    static unsigned ref_count_;

    DynamicInitializer() {
        if(!ref_count_++)
            instance_ = new T;
    }

    ~DynamicInitializer() {
        if(!--ref_count_)
            delete instance_;
    }

    operator T&() const { return *instance_; }
    T* operator->() const { return instance_; }

    DynamicInitializer(DynamicInitializer const&) = delete;
    DynamicInitializer& operator=(DynamicInitializer const&) = delete;
};

template<class T>
unsigned DynamicInitializer<T>::ref_count_ = 0;

template<class T>
T* DynamicInitializer<T>::instance_ = 0;
```

Usage:

```
// MyLogger.h

struct MyLogger
{
    void log(char const*);
};

// const makes static storage.
DynamicInitializer<MyLogger> const my_global_logger;
```

Now, whenever `MyLogger.h` is included, `my_global_logger` is guaranteed to be initialized before its first use, e.g. `my_global_logger->log("hello");`

Comment: Please copy the most relevant portion of the external web site, not just a link. SO answers should stand on their own, the link should just be used to add supporting details.

Comment: Which standard library implementation uses this mess? :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit This is the standard way. In other words, the question is which standard library implementation does it differently?

Comment: @Maxim Did you mean, the _conventional_ way? The standard does not specify implementation.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit _"The [standard iostream] objects are constructed, and their associations are established at some time prior to or during first time an object of class basic_ios<charT,traits>::Init is constructed, and in any case before the body of main begins execution." (27.3/2 [lib.iostream.objects])_

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit This is a portable way to enforce dynamic initialization order across different translation units documented in the C++ standard. It probably does not mean that the standard streams must be initialized using this specific mechanism, however, if this method is used, it is required by the standard to work.

Comment: I just find it ironic that comments in the implementation itself admit that there is a far less hacky way to do it, given compiler support.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I do not understand why you call it a hack.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: Okay